# Mount mapped device on boot

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, boot, initrd, device-mapper

I have a Linux system with 2.4 kernel version. I need to make a mapping device through **device-mapper** for root partition and mount to it at boot time.

I need to use special mapper type (not a standart one like **linear** or **mirror**). So, I tried to write my own kernel module, implementing necessary functions (now it just transfers the query to a real device).

I used [this](http://techgmm.blogspot.ru/p/writing-your-own-device-mapper-target.html) article as a start point. I've done some changes in its code, so now it looks like this:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/device-mapper.h>

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,32)
#include <linux/bio.h>
#endif

#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(2,4,32)
#include <linux/mm.h>
#endif

struct Sddm_target
{
    struct dm_dev *dev;
    sector_t start;
};

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(2,4,32)
static int sddm_target_map(struct dm_target *ti, struct buffer_head *bh, int rw, union map_info *map_context)
#elif LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,32)
static int sddm_target_map(struct dm_target *ti, struct bio *bio, union map_info *map_context)
#else
static int sddm_target_map(struct dm_target *ti, struct bio *bio)
#endif
{
    struct Sddm_target *mdt;

    mdt = (struct Sddm_target *) ti->private;

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(2,4,32)
    bh->b_dev = mdt->dev->bdev->bd_dev;
#else
    bio->bi_bdev = mdt->dev->bdev;
#endif

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(2,4,32)
    submit_bh(rw, bh);
#elif LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,32)
    submit_bio(bio->bi_rw, bio);
#else
    submit_bio(bio);
#endif

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(2,4,32)
    return 0;
#else
    return DM_MAPIO_SUBMITTED;
#endif
}

static int sddm_target_ctr(struct dm_target *ti, unsigned int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct Sddm_target *mdt;
    unsigned long start;
    unsigned long len;
    int err;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        ti->error = "Invalid argument count";
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    mdt = (struct Sddm_target*)kmalloc(sizeof(struct Sddm_target), GFP_KERNEL);

    if (mdt == NULL)
    {
        printk(KERN_CRIT "\n Mdt is null\n");
        ti->error = "dm-basic_target: Cannot allocate linear context";
        return -ENOMEM;
    }       

    if (sscanf(argv[1], "%lu", &start) != 1)
    {
        ti->error = "dm-basic_target: Invalid deviceee sector";
        kfree(mdt);
        printk(KERN_CRIT "\n>>out function basic_target_ctr with errorrrrrrrrrr \n");           
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    mdt->start = (sector_t)start;

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(2,4,32)
    err = dm_get_device(ti, argv[0], ti->begin, ti->len, dm_table_get_mode(ti->table), &mdt->dev);
#else
    err = dm_get_device(ti, argv[0], dm_table_get_mode(ti->table), &mdt->dev);
#endif
    if (err)
    {
        ti->error = "dm-basic_target: Device lookup failed";
        kfree(mdt);
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    ti->private = mdt;

    return 0;
}

static void sddm_target_dtr(struct dm_target *ti)
{
    struct Sddm_target *mdt = (struct Sddm_target *) ti->private;

    dm_put_device(ti, mdt->dev);
    kfree(mdt);
}

static struct target_type sddm_target = {
        .name = "sddm_target",
        .version = {1,0,0},
        .module = THIS_MODULE,
        .ctr = sddm_target_ctr,
        .dtr = sddm_target_dtr,
        .map = sddm_target_map,
};

static int __init init_sddm_target(void)
{
    int result;

    result = dm_register_target(&sddm_target);

    return 0;
}

static void __exit cleanup_sddm_target(void)
{
    dm_unregister_target(&sddm_target);
}

module_init(init_sddm_target);

module_exit(cleanup_sddm_target);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

You see, that the main function is to change target device to another (real) and resubmit query:

```
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(2,4,32)
    bh->b_dev = MKDEV(3, 3);
#else
    bio->bi_bdev = mdt->dev->bdev;
#endif

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(2,4,32)
    submit_bh(rw, bh);
#elif LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,32)
    submit_bio(bio->bi_rw, bio);
#else
    submit_bio(bio);
#endif
```

Row `bh->b_dev = MKDEV(3, 3);` is wrong, but I don't know where is the appropriate device number located, so I tried to calculate it myself.

The next my step was to change **initrd** image and **linuxrc** file in it:

```
#!/bin/nash

echo "Loading dm-mod.o module"
insmod /lib/dm-mod.o 
echo "Loading scsi_mod.o module"
insmod /lib/scsi_mod.o 
echo "Loading sd_mod.o module"
insmod /lib/sd_mod.o 
echo "Loading cdrom.o module"
insmod /lib/cdrom.o 
echo "Loading sr_mod.o module"
insmod /lib/sr_mod.o 
echo "Loading sg.o module"
insmod /lib/sg.o 
echo "Loading usbcore.o module"
insmod /lib/usbcore.o 
echo "Loading usb-storage.o module"
insmod /lib/usb-storage.o 
sleep 5
echo "Loading jbd.o module"
insmod /lib/jbd.o 
echo "Loading ext3.o module"
insmod /lib/ext3.o 
insmod /lib//sddm_target.o
echo Mounting /proc filesystem
mount -t proc /proc /proc
echo Creating block devices
mkdevices /dev
echo Creating root device

echo "======================================"
ld-linux.so.2 /bin/dmsetup create root_part /opt/bin/table
echo "======================================"

mkrootdev /dev/root
echo 0x0100 > /proc/sys/kernel/real-root-dev

echo "MOUNT START==============="
mount -o acl,nosecdel,secrm --ro -t ext3 /dev/mapper/root_part /sysroot
echo "MOUNT DONE==============="

pivot_root /sysroot /sysroot/initrd
umount /initrd/proc
```

where **sddm_target** - is my kernel module.

Table file contains:

```
0 62814150 sddm_target /dev/hda3 0
```

Mapping device appears in given directory, so it looks like everything is good. But when I try to boot my system, I get several runs of **sddm_target_map** function called with device mounting and then boot holds with the message:

```
kjournald started. Commit intervel 5 seconds
```

Some googling helped me to understand, that this message is printed by filesystem check program. But what is the reason of it - I don't know.

I need help!

Comment: That message is harmless. Anyway, whoever forces you to use a 2.4 kernel is whom you are paying for support. Why are you asking here?

Comment: @CL. because stackoverflow is question-answer system for programmers... Am I wrong?